# Is there a way to know whether a h5 page is loading with webview in android platform?

Tags: android, html, webview, filesize

Is there a listener that I can know the page is loading or loaded? In general, I know the page is loaded finally by this listener method:

```
 @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
```

But when it is paging or paged, there is no any listener infomation I can get. The only changed things are:

```
@Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }
```

Is there a way to know whether a h5 page is loading with webview in android platform or I can listen the h5 page's size changed?

Answer (score 0):

I find an another way to solve this problem.

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
             webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
            "console.log(\"nodes'number->\"+document.getElementsByTagName(\"*\").length)" +
            "})()");
            }
}
```

when the nodes's num is not changed, it is loaded eventually.